# Remove items from List<string> where substring is duplicated (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

Lets say I have a list

```
TEST1 10:05:45
TEST2 10:03:23
TEST3 10:01:28
TEST2 13:03:23
TEST3 16:01:28
```

I would like to filter my list and remove all lines where the name is duplicated,
so my output would be this here:

```
TEST1 10:05:45
```

This is what I have tryed so far:

```cs
List<string> numberList = new List<string>() {
    "TEST1 10:05:45", "TEST2 10:03:23", "TEST3 10:01:28", 
    "TEST2 13:03:23", "TEST3 16:01:28" };
          
foreach (var x in numberList
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
    .Select(g => g.Key))
{
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work since the Time Stamps are different altough the name is the same

Anyone got a clue what I can do here ?

Comment: Before you use `GroupBy()` you have to use `Split(' ')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments show a completely different input than shown in your question. The string you are trying to parse is a HTML string. Not a string with space separated items. Example (excerpt from longer text):

```xml
<div><span class="watchlist " data-wkn="A1CSR6" title="Zur..." />
```

You are searching for duplicates of the key `data-wkn`.

While it is generally not a good idea to parse HTML with regex, it might work with this simple scenario. The idea is to search for a text embedded between `data-wkn="` and `"`. This can be achieved with the general regex pattern `(?<=prefix)find(?=suffix)` which matches an expression (`find`) between a `prefix` and a `suffix`.

```cs
string key = Regex.Match(input, "(?<=data-wkn=\").*?(?=\")").Value;
```

Note that we have to escape the double quotes with `\"` in string literals in C#.

With

- `prefix` = `data-wkn="`, the string before the key (with `"` escaped as `\"`).
- `find` = `.*?` any number of any character, but a few as possible.
- `suffix` = `"`, the string after the key (with `"` escaped as `\"`).

Usage:

```cs
var filteredList = numberList
   .GroupBy(s => Regex.Match(s, "(?<=data-wkn=\").*?(?=\")").Value)
   .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
   .Select(g => g.First());
```

See: [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Comment: wow works, really nice, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the complete string as grouping key, but a substring that goes to the first space:

```
numberList
   .GroupBy(i => i.Substring(0, i.IndexOf(' ')))
   .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
   .Select(g => g.First())
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yiCbef

Comment: but this TEST1 where I would want TEST 1 10:05:45 edit: WORKS NOW THANKS A LOT

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer. Don't select the key, but the first item of your grouping.

Comment: or `.GroupBy(s => s.Split(' ')[0])`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes If the string is very long and contains more spaces, this will lead to unnecessary allocation of strings.

Comment: Yes, but it has the advantage to work even when there is no space character.

Comment: is there a way of searching for this substring like this : .GroupBy(i => i.Substring(0, i.IndexOf(FindTextBetween(string a, string b))), so one would search the item rather than using space ?

Comment: @HassanAblatar, please show us the real strings!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/swM4Swx8 this is one item/string,  `data-wkn="A1CSR6"` should be the GroupBy key

Comment: @HassanAblatar, this is quite a different situation as you posted in your question and completely invalidates (good) answers given so far.

Comment: I didnt post it beccause I thought it would confuse people, I thought there would be some answer I can use generally :( thanks though for your helpl

Comment: @HassanAblatar Sometimes it is good to simplify a problem before you ask a question, but you have to be sure that you can adapt the answer to your real problem. If you simplify your problem too much, this won't be possible.